# (PHP) Reading a blob image with Imagick

Tags: php, symfony, blob, imagick

I'm trying to create an jpg with Imagick but I have an error in `readImageBlob`

```
$image = new \Imagick();
$chart = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>' . $chart;
$image->readImageBlob( $chart );
$image->setImageFormat("jpeg");
```

It says:

**negative or zero image size `/tmp/magick-29893mIHq2qQrLKKP' @ error/image.c/SetImageExtent/2601**

Pointing to the line that I mentioned before. I have previously defined `$chart`as:

```
$chart = '<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" class="highcharts-root" style="font-family:"lucida grande", "lucida sans unicode", arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" xmlns="http://... (ETC) ...g></svg>';
```

Could be a problem with how is `$chart` defined?
What and how should I look for `$chart`in order to see if is correct defined or not?

The problem is reading a Blob, not converting a svg to a blob

Comment: `Imagick->readImageBlob` expects **binary data** http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimageblob.php

Comment: So, $chart contains a svg, how can handle it then with Imagick to read it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read an SVG with a given size using PHP Imagick?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226232/how-to-read-an-svg-with-a-given-size-using-php-imagick)

Comment: If you run the image (plus the prefix you're adding) through a validator does it validate?

Comment: @apokryfos how can I do that? that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: Now I'm using `readImage($chart)`and I get: Invalid filename provided

Comment: Try using https://validator.nu/

Comment: `readImage()`expects an URL of an image? Is there a way to pass it a php var that contains my svg?

Comment: I downloaded an SVG from http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series (using the export functionality) and the file includes a DOCTYPE and the xml version is already in there. Are you sure you're exporting the file correctly?

Comment: Well, I was following this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903461/how-to-read-svg-string-in-imagick that's why I was using readImageBlob first, and my svg is like that example

Comment: Argh... the problem is with the formart of my avg, the $chart. My code works ok using other svg's, and I HAVE to use radImageBlob

Comment: @apokryfos by the way, the svg is "The document validates according to the specified schema(s)."

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was using readImageBlob with a svg file. I made this to read a binary:

```
//Set 2 temp files, one for the svg that I'll make and another one for the image that I will use later
$filesvg = '/tmp/chart.svg';
$chartImage = '/tmp/tempchartimg.jpg';

//the svg had to use that header
$chart = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>' . $chart;

//I'll save the svg in the temp file made before
file_put_contents($filesvg,$chart);
//Coverting and save in as 'binaryImage' file the svg to jpg
$binaryImage = shell_exec("convert $filesvg jpg:-");

//The the usal Imagick part:
$image = new \Imagick();

//Now I can read a binary file 
$image->readImageBlob($binaryImage);
$image->setImageFormat("jpg");
$image->setImageCompressionQuality(90);
$image->resizeImage(600, 400, \imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
$image->writeImage($chartImage);

//rest of my code...
```